# jodatime DateTime millis cannot be set with actual epoch millis

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jodatime

I'm looking for a reasonable way to set the value of jodatime's DateTime millis.  While debugging in Intellij IDEA (v15), I'm looking at the following code:

```
public String getDayOfWeek(String timezone) {
  DateTime now = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID(timezone));
  return now.dayOfWeek().getAsText();
}
```

If I breakpoint the return statement for the purpose of mutating the value of `now` by changing the `millis` field of the `DateTime` instance to reflect a different (valid) epoch time with millis, Intellij errors that the value I'm attempting to set exceeds the capacity of `int`.  It makes sense since epoch with millis is 13-digits and IIRC `int` can only store 2^32-1.

There isn't a visible field in the `DateTime` instance for epoch time without millis.  I can successfully set the value with the 10-digit epoch time without millis, but clearly that's not going to evaluate properly; I only mention it to say that I'm able to set within-range values in the debugger successfully.

What options are there?  Alternately, is there a more elegant way with jodatime to derive the current day of the week that also allows me to mutate the value?  The caller doesn't assign the return value, rather, simply uses it for comparison.  I don't want to scrap jodatime since this method is part of a quite large class of methods that all use it.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to do. `DateTime` is an immutable type; you're not meant to be able to set it. Also, when you say "millis" is that a *field* within `DateTime`? If so, I wouldn't start messing with that. Why don't you just create a *new* `DateTime` with the epoch millis and relevant time zone? Why do you want a mutable type? (There *is* `MutableDateTime`, but I'd strongly recommend avoiding it...)

Comment: yes, millis is a field; I updated the text to show that.
I'm validating some logic in an app that is sensitive to server time (e.g. what day of the week is it, what time is it in the user's timezone, etc.) and I'd like to exercise that logic without waiting for actual logic boundaries to occur.  For example, the logic behaves differently on weekends vs weekdays. On a weekday I'd like to mutate this in the debugger to 'pretend' it's Saturday.  Doing that appears to require a change to the millis field, but because a millisecond epoch time is required, the DateTime instance overflows on setting

Comment: I would strongly recommend *not* doing this using the debugger and messing with implementation details. Instead, use dependency injection and a "clock" abstraction (a service which provides a concept of "now") so that you can write tests for whatever scenario you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you ran into this issue because the value used was interpreted as an `int` instead of a `long`? You can use one of the `DateTime` constructors that takes a `long` parameter to specify the date and time in milliseconds. For example:

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

public class JodaTimeMillis {
    public static void main(final String[] arguments) {
        new JodaTimeMillis().run();
    }

    private void run() {
        DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Amsterdam");
        String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS";
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);

        for (int milliseconds = 619; milliseconds < 629; milliseconds++) {
            DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(1234567890000L + milliseconds, timeZone);
            System.out.println(milliseconds + ": " + dateTimeFormatter.print(dateTime));
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the following output (on my laptop), which shows that the milliseconds part can be specified:

```
619: 02/14/2009 00:31:30.619
620: 02/14/2009 00:31:30.620
621: 02/14/2009 00:31:30.621
622: 02/14/2009 00:31:30.622
623: 02/14/2009 00:31:30.623
624: 02/14/2009 00:31:30.624
625: 02/14/2009 00:31:30.625
626: 02/14/2009 00:31:30.626
627: 02/14/2009 00:31:30.627
628: 02/14/2009 00:31:30.628
```

Do you want to run tests from the debugger? You could also consider using [unit tests](http://junit.org/).

Comment: Thanks. This isn't what I'd consider a standard scenario; the code is definitely covered with unit tests; in this case I'm dealing with a QA org that "must see behavior on a live, integrated system via manual testing" before promoting it forward. Short of having manually exercising the code at logic boundaries, just looking for options to provide an ad hoc solution

Comment: Sounds like very thorough quality assurance! Is using a `DateTime` constructor with a `long` value an option for your scenario?